# Randomly selecting one episode per ID in long dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, random, grouping

I have a long format dataset where each ID has multiple episodes, and multiple rows per episode. I would like to select at random just one episode per ID, and all its associated rows.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
    episode = c(1,2,2,1,1,1,2))
df
  id episode
 1  1       1
 2  1       2
 3  1       2
 4  2       1
 5  2       1
 6  2       1
 7  2       2
```

... And I want to be left with this dataset:

```
df2
  id episode
1  1       2
2  1       2
3  2       1
4  2       1
5  2       1
```

Comment: Your expected output is showing multiple episodes per `ID`, from what I can tell.  Is this a typo?

Comment: `df[df$episode != df$id, ]`

Comment: It's showing that for ID 1 I have selected only episode 2, and for ID 2 I have selected only episode 1. This is what I am trying to obtain. Sorry if it wasn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R method with `ave` and subsetting.

```
set.seed(1234)
df[df$episode == ave(df$episode, df$id, FUN=function(x) sample(x, size=1)),]
```

Here, `ave` applies `sample` to each id, selecting a single episode and returns a vector the length of the number of rows of the data.frame with a single episode per id. The data.frame is subset by comparing the episodes in each id to the returned vector.

This instance returns

```
  id episode
1  1       1
4  2       1
5  2       1
6  2       1
```

In `data.table`, you might do

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
setDT(df)[df[, sample(episode, 1), by=id], on=.(id, "episode"=V1)]
```

This will return the same result as above (except it will be a data.table rather than a data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using base R:

1) sample the original data

```
dfsampled <- df[sample(seq_len(nrow(df))),]
```

2) merge non-duplicated sample data with original data:

```
merge(dfsampled[!duplicated(dfsampled$id),], df, all.x = TRUE)

#  id episode
#1  1       2
#2  1       2
#3  2       1
#4  2       1
#5  2       1
```

And a dplyr-approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(episode == sample(unique(episode), 1))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id episode
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       2
2     1       2
3     2       1
4     2       1
5     2       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
set.seed(123)
df%>%group_by(id)%>%
mutate(new=sample(episode,1))%>%
filter(episode!=new)%>%
select(id,episode)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id    episode
#    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1       2
#2     1       2
#3     2       1
#4     2       1
#5     2       1
```